# Unity 2D Jagged Array , Array index is out of range

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have this 2D Array which is giving me a *Array index is out of range*, problem. What is the cause of this problem and how can i solve this ?

**EDIT**: Yep, sorry about that. I will include what i will want to do here:

So im trying to make jagged array which.
So i have a number of `platforms`, `numOfPlatforms`
I want to go through them, and each platform has its `Size` which is `randomXSize`.
And now, i want mark a point in each platform which is every 0.5, thats why i made

```
(randomXSize - 0.5)
```

But i don't know how many times i will need to do that for so i made

```
randomXSizeSegments = randomXSize * 2;
```

To calculate how many 0.5 will be for each `randomXSize`.

So in other words,
If the first platform '0' has a randomXSize of 3

I want the array `randomXSizeSegments` to be looking like this

```
randomXSizeSegments[1][0] = 3
randomXSizeSegments[0][1] = 2.5
randomXSizeSegments[0][2] = 2
randomXSizeSegments[0][3] = 1.5
randomXSizeSegments[0][4] = 1
randomXSizeSegments[0][5] = 0.5
randomXSizeSegments[0][6] = 0
```

And if second platform '1' has a `randomXSize` of 7
I want the array `randomXSizeSegments` to be looking like this

```
randomXSizeSegments[1][0] = 7
randomXSizeSegments[1][1] = 6.5
randomXSizeSegments[1][2] = 6
randomXSizeSegments[1][3] = 5.5
randomXSizeSegments[1][4] = 5
randomXSizeSegments[1][5] = 4.5
randomXSizeSegments[1][6] = 4
randomXSizeSegments[1][7] = 3.5
randomXSizeSegments[1][8] = 3
randomXSizeSegments[1][9] = 2.5
randomXSizeSegments[1][10] = 2
randomXSizeSegments[1][11] = 1.5
randomXSizeSegments[1][12] = 1
randomXSizeSegments[1][13] = 0


void Debugging_One() {

    for(int a = 0; a < numOfPlatforms; a = a + 1) {
        randomXPosSegments = new int[a][];
        randomXSizeSegments = randomXSize * 2;
        //Debug.Log(a);
        //Debug.Log(randomXSizeSegments);
        for(int b = 0; b < randomXSizeSegments; b = b + 1) {
            // randomXPosSegments[a][b] = 0;
            randomXPosSegments[a] = new int[] {(int)(randomXSize - 0.5)};
            //Debug.Log(b);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration of your outer for-loop, `randomXPosSegments = new int[a][]` creates an "empty" array since `a = 0`. When you then try to access the "0th" (i.e. first) element of that array, it throws that exception since there isn't a position `[0]` to access.

To create an array with one element, you need to declare it to have a size of `1`:

```
var singleElementArray = new int[1];
singleElementArray[0] = 42;
Debug.WriteLine(singleElementArray[0]); // Prints '42'
```

If you give it a size of `0`. There isn't a "0th" position that exists to assign to:

```
var singleElementArray = new int[0];
singleElementArray[0] = 42; // Throws IndexOutOfRangeException
```

I'm not sure how to help you solve this since you haven't explained what you are trying to accomplish and existing code doesn't make sense (e.g. you have an iterator `b` you never use, you keep on setting `randomXPosSegments[a]` to a new empty array).

**Edit:**

A few things first:

- To store decimal values like `0.5`, `randomXPosSegments` will need to be an array of `double` instead of `int`. We also need to create this outside the loop, or we'll keep creating a new empty array on each iteration. Like wise, you need to initialize `randomXPosSegments[a]` outside the inner for-loop or you'll just reset it each time.
- I created a `GetRandomXSize()` function, since right now it's value never changes.
- Inside the inner for-loop, I'm using `randomXSize - (0.5 * b)` to get values like `7, 6.5, ...`. `b` will start off as `0`, so on the first iteration, it will just be `randomXSize`. Then it'll subtract a `0.5` for each time it's been through the loop.
- To get `0` as the last result inside the jagged array, I had to change the condition on the inner for-loop to `b <= randomXSizeSegments` and make sure I initialize it to be big enough to fit the results (notice the `+1` in `new double[randomXSizeSegments + 1]`).

Here's the code that works for me.

```
var randomXPosSegments = new double[numOfPlatforms][];
for(int a = 0; a < numOfPlatforms; a = a + 1) {
    var randomXSize = GetRandomXSize();
    var randomXSizeSegments = randomXSize * 2;
    randomXPosSegments[a] = new double[randomXSizeSegments + 1];
    for(int b = 0; b <= randomXSizeSegments; b = b + 1) {
        randomXPosSegments[a][b] = randomXSize - (0.5 * b);
    }
}
```